# How to insert string NODATA before last word in certain lines depending on string before?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The batch script below is for reformatting a text file which works well so far.

A string consisting of any word character or dot or hyphen is interpreted as **word** in this context.

There is the requirement to insert `NODATA` as last but one **word** if the string left to last **word** is none of the following strings which should be searched for respectively compared case-insensitive:

- `API`
- `Server Module`
- `Version`

Input data example:

```
Check Masterdata API 3.1.8 
Core Server Module 3.1.8-P02 
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P 
Core resources 1.2.1
```

Expected output data:

```
Check Masterdata API 3.1.8 
Core Server Module 3.1.8-P02 
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P 
Core resources NODATA 1.2.1
```

I don't have any idea which code to add to the batch file for this requirement because of pure knowledge on regular expressions. I think it could be done also with `jrepl.bat`.

Has anyone a suggestion for adding an appropriate `jrepl.bat` command line above the existing call of this batch file to insert `NODATA` at right position on right lines?

Script:

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)[^\w.\-]+([\w.\-]+)$" ",$1,$2" /F "%tempFile2%" /O "%tempFile3%"
```

Comment: "I need" is not a question, so please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Comment: So are you saying all your input lines should have three words and then a version code?  If it doesn't have three words then add the word NODATA as the third word?

Comment: @Squashman, No, if the word before last word is not API (or) Server module (or) Version, then I should add NODATA before last word.

Comment: So the version codes are considered a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to add the following two lines above the line calling already `jrepl.bat`.

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "\b([\w.\-]+)$" "NODATA $1" /F "%tempFile2%" /O -
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(API|Server Module|Version)[\t ]+NODATA" "$1" /I /F "%tempFile2%" /O -
```

The first line results in inserting `NODATA` left to last **word** in all lines of temporary file 2.

The second line searches case-insensitive for `API` **or** `Server Module` **or** `Version` in a marking/capturing group followed by 1 or more tabs or spaces and the just before inserted `NODATA`. The replace removes the tabs/spaces and `NODATA` and keeps `API` **or** `Server Module` **or** `Version` as found in the line.

Answer (score 0):

In the section of code you required help with, I used delayed expansion, double quotes and indentation in those areas where you hadn't and prevented echoing an unnecessary trailing space in `temp.txt`.

```bat
rem Not Working Starts

for /f "delims=" %%j in (%tempFile2%) do (
    set "Fileline=%%j"
    set "Fileline_API=!Fileline:API=!"
    set "Fileline_Client=!Fileline:Client=!"
    set "Fileline_ServerModule=!Fileline:Server module=!"
    set "Fileline_Component=!Fileline:Component=!"
    set "Fileline_GlobalsModule=!Fileline:Globals module=!"
    set "Fileline_ClientBaseModule=!Fileline:Client base module=!"
    set "Fileline_GlobalBaseModule=!Fileline:Global base module=!"
    set "Fileline_ServerBaseModule=!Fileline:Server base module=!"
    set "Fileline_Global=!Fileline:Global=!"

    if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_API!" (
        if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_Client!" (
            if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_ServerModule!" (
                if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_Component!" (
                    if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_GlobalsModule!" (
                        if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_ClientBaseModule!" (
                            if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_GlobalBaseModule!" (
                                if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_ServerBaseModule!" (
                                    if "!Fileline!"=="!Fileline_Global!" (
                                        >temp.txt echo !Fileline!

                                        rem Section to get the last word but one and do if else conditions

                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

rem Not Working Ends
```

---

As you don't appear to need many of the variables elsewhere in your script you could of course shorten it still further.

```bat
rem Not Working Starts

for /f "delims=" %%j in (%tempFile2%) do (
    set "Fileline=%%j"
    if "%%j"=="!Fileline:API=!" (
        if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Client=!" (
            if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Server module=!" (
                if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Component=!" (
                    if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Globals module=!" (
                        if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Client base module=!" (
                            if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Global base module=!" (
                                if "%%j"=="Fileline:Server base module=!" (
                                    if "%%j"=="!Fileline:Global=!" (
                                        >temp.txt echo %%j

                                        rem Section to get the last word but one and do if else conditions

                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

rem Not Working Ends
```

---

Any problems which may exist in your logic etc. is however outside of the scope of these answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding your desired output goal.

Given your input of.

```
Check Masterdata API 3.1.8 
Core Server Module 3.1.8-P02 
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P 
Core resources 1.2.1
```

You can use this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN (input.txt) DO (
        SET "line=%%G"
        SET "line=!line:api=!"
        SET "line=!line:server module=!"
        SET "line=!line:version=!"
        IF "%%G"=="!line!" (
            CALL :NODATA "%%G"
        ) ELSE (
            echo %%G
        )
)
pause
GOTO :EOF

:NODATA
set i=0
set "x=%~1"
set "xb=%x: =" & set "xl=%"
set "newline=!x:%xl%=NODATA %xl%!"
echo %newline%
goto :EOF
```

And this is the output I get from it.

```
Check Masterdata API 3.1.8
Core Server Module 3.1.8-P02
Check Subsystem version 3.1.8-11P
Core resources NODATA 1.2.1
```

You have so much code in your original question, I am not really sure where you need this in your code.  I just coded based on you input and output example.